# Drupal Quiz Module for retake exam

Tags: views, quiz

I am trying to implement [Quiz](http://drupal.org/project/quiz) module in Drupal 6

The quiz scores will be tied to their accounts, with the ability to retake a quiz if permission is granted by Admin. How can I do this?

Also someone should not be able to advance to the next video unless they have scored a high enough score on the quiz or they have a password to open the next video.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the [Quiz module](http://drupal.org/project/quiz). It also has an active [Drupal Group](http://groups.drupal.org/quiz) :)

> The Quiz module provides tools for authoring and administering quizzes through Drupal. A quiz is given as a series of questions, with only one question appearing per page. Scores are then stored in the database.
>
> This module provides tools for
>
> 1. Online courses (Audio and Video enabled)
> 2. Self-learning programs
> 3. Training programs
> 4. Supplementary classroom activites

Comment: I need with the ability to retake a quiz if permission is granted by Admin(how to do this ?

Comment: sorry for late reply, but I think that the functionality needs to be implemented. You can do it so by [creating a custom module](http://drupal.org/node/231276)